# Find all values such that the series converge:

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find all the values of $p\in\mathbb R$ such that the following series converge:

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty (\log k)^{p\log k}$$

I would like hints only.

I've tried using the exponential function (thinking that e^log(log)...might get me somewhere) or ...the ln(1+x) series and rewriting the variable k as 1+x and starting the series at x=1 ... and also expanding in Taylor series (for ln(1+x)) to order 3 and using Big-O notation for the remainder terms, but still haven't gotten anywhere with these two approaches.

Thanks,

Edit: I will try the ratio test now...hmm...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** the ratio test fails.
$$
(\log k)^{p \log k} = e^{p\log(\log(k))\log k} = k^{p \log (\log(k))}
$$

Comment: If I right, series converges for $p < 0$.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Yep! Per the question, however, I'm sticking to hints.

Comment: Nice hint @Omnomnomnom.  Unfortunately, I am now stuck with the series of $k^{plog(log(k))}$ or $k^{log(log(k))p}$ .  Can you offer another hint?  Thanks,

Comment: @LebronJames comparison test with $\sum k^{-2}$

Comment: oh, gosh...I was so stubborn :-(  , and kept trying to go for a geometric series...thanks so much, @Omnomnomnom!!

Comment: Hi @Omnomnomnom, so I have that, for convergence it must be true that p< 1/e(log2) - I gave the right hand term an upper bound, since the inequality should be true for all k.  I then go over 3 cases.  Cases 1 and 2 are simple: p can't be zero or positive, or else the series diverges by the $n^{th}$ term test.  So p<0 ...but for *which* negative values, I am not certain of.  Or, so long as my inequality is satisfied, p< 1/e(log2), *any* p<0 will work?  I feel I'm making sort of a weak statement here...

Comment: *"for convergence it must be true that p< 1/e(log2)"*. Nope.  How'd you decide that?

Comment: The inequality doesn't need to be true for **all** $k$, just **all except finitely many** $k$.  That is, we'd need to show that there exists a $k_0$ such that the inequality holds for $k > k_0$

Comment: Ah, I see (I think).  So, split the series up into a finite term and tail-end term, say, the tail sums from k = M+1 to infinity.  Then the inequality p<1/elog(k) must be satisfied for convergence, where k is greater than or equal to M+1.  But, any negative value of p works, so the series converges for p<0.  Is this ok?  I still feel I am making a necessary but *not* sufficient statement here...hmm...

Comment: of course, taking k large enough guarantees that the exponent in the summand will be < -1, when we take any p <0.

Comment: For $p<0$, $\exists K$ such that $k>K\implies p\log(\log k)<-2$.  Thus, the series is dominated by the series for $\frac{1}{k^2}$ for $k>K$.   And that is that.

Comment: Note that you should separately show *divergence* for $p\geq 0$

Comment: Ok, got it @Omnomnomnom - thanks so much for your help!! :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for the statement, @Dr.MV.  I also refined my upper bound to be p< 1/elog(M+1) to make use of the idea from Omnomnomnom that the bound should be true for all *except finitely many k*.  But the bound is trivially true for p<0.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  Really glad my comment was useful.  Will you be playing for  Cleveland next year?

Comment: You should comment more on my work this summer, @Dr.MV, if you want :-)  Regarding my basketball career, yes - I will be keeping my talents in Cleveland for next year.  But you never know...

Comment: The folks in Cleveland will be happy to hear ... that you're adept at analyzing infinite series ... oh, and they might be a slightly happy to hear about your plans to stay ... ;-)))))

Comment: I plan on making my teammates read Ahlfors' *Complex Analysis* cover-to-cover during road trips next season.  The book is about 300 dollars, but I should have enough funds to buy a few copies from Amazon, @Dr.MV :-)